# Indices of parts of data containing null values

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am looking for an algorithm which will allow me to search and get indices of all gaps (nans) in a Series, where indices refer to start and end of "partitions". I couldn't find a solution so I ended up with codes created by myself. Everything is OK except both approaches seem a little bit slow. I was wondering if there are ways to optimise the code.

I tried two approaches. The first with a simple for-loop over all indices and checking for continuation. The other drops nan values and then again check for continuation using the List Comprehension. The latter approach is faster.

I was wondering if there are better ways to improve the speed or perhaps I missed something that is already built-in. Thanks.

The data:

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create an object with sample data
w = pd.Series(np.sin(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0,1,2880)))
# Insert a few gaps with missing values
for i in np.arange(0, 1500, 200):
    w.loc[w.index[0]+i:w.index[0]+i+100] = np.nan
w.loc[2880-100:] = np.nan```
````

The first approach:

```
# Get indices
# `l_nans` stores the first and the last index of each gap
t0 = time()
for c in range(1000):
    i_nans = w[w.isnull()].index.to_numpy()
    len_nans = i_nans.shape[0]
    f, l, p, n = np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan
    l_nans = list()
    i = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(i_nans.tolist()):
        if not np.isnan(n):
            p = n
        n = e
        if np.isnan(f):
            f = e
        if (n-p) > 1:
            l = p
            l_nans.append((f, l))
            f, l = e, np.nan
        if i == len_nans-1:
            l = n
            l_nans.append((f, l))
print(l_nans)
print(time() - t0)

[(0, 100), (200, 300), (400, 500), (600, 700), (800, 900), (1000, 1100), (1200, 1300), (1400, 1500), (2780, 2879)]
3.1106319427490234
```

The second approach:

```
# Get indices
# `l_nans` stores the first and the last index of each gap
t0 = time()
for c in range(1000):
    v = w.drop(w[w.isnull()].index, axis=0)
    l_nans = [(e[0]+1, e[1]-1) for e in zip(v.index[:-1], v.index[1:]) if e[1]-e[0] > 1]
    if not any(v.index.isin([w.index[0]])):
        l_nans.insert(0, (0, v.first_valid_index()-1))
    if not any(v.index.isin([w.index[-1]])):
        l_nans.append((v.last_valid_index()+1, w.index[-1]))
print(l_nans)
print(time() - t0)

[(0, 100), (200, 300), (400, 500), (600, 700), (800, 900), (1000, 1100), (1200, 1300), (1400, 1500), (2780, 2879)]
1.8505527973175049
```

---

EDIT.

I realised some parts of my real data has single nan values. So the example data is following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create an object with sample data
w = pd.Series(np.sin(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0,1,2880)))
# Insert a few gaps with missing values
for i in np.arange(0, 1500, 200):
    w.loc[w.index[0]+i:w.index[0]+i+100] = np.nan
w.loc[2880-100:] = np.nan
w.loc[1600] = np.nan
w.loc[1700] = np.nan
```

Comment: can you post few lines of df test data and desired result?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi `w` here is the test data, the desired result is the list of tuples below each approach.

Comment: I've slightly changed the question and added a few comments to improve the clarity. The `w` (a `pandas` `Series` object) contains the sample data with the `NaN`s and `l_nans` is a list object that stores all range indices of each gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `intervals_extract` recipe from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-make-a-list-of-intervals-with-sequential-numbers/

```
import itertools 
  
def intervals_extract(iterable): 
      
    iterable = sorted(set(iterable)) 
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(iterable), 
    lambda t: t[1] - t[0]): 
        group = list(group) 
        yield [group[0][1], group[-1][1]]
```

`itertools.groupby` groups data together *as long as the keyfunction returns the same value*. The key function is the difference between two successive values which is 1 as long as they belong to the same interval and something larger otherwise. This is also we we use the set and sort it: To avoid duplicate or wrongly ordered values. Therefore we get an iterators for each interval (`group`). The only thing left is to consume the iterator with the `list` function and yield the first and last value of each. For this case it would be a bit simpler to directly print the values, but like this it stays a bit more generalizable.

As input simply use the index where you have `NaN`s:

```
In [72]: list(intervals_extract(w[w.isna()].index))                                                                                                                                                        
Out[72]: 
[[0, 100],
 [200, 300],
 [400, 500],
 [600, 700],
 [800, 900],
 [1000, 1100],
 [1200, 1300],
 [1400, 1500],
 [1600, 1600],
 [1700, 1700],
 [2780, 2879]]
```

```
In [73]: %timeit list(intervals_extract(w[w.isna()].index))                                                                                                                                                
485 µs ± 5.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

EDIT: Explained the idea behind the `intervals_extract` function

Comment: This looks pretty neat. Could you explain what group represent ?

Comment: It's working and it's fast. I am trying to understand how groupby works but having some problems but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make this loop even faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df = pd.Series(np.sin(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0,1,2880)))
for i in np.arange(0, 1500, 200):
    df.loc[df.index[0]+i:df.index[0]+i+100] = np.nan
df.loc[2880-100:] = np.nan


start_time = time.time()
data = df.index[df.isnull() == True].tolist() + [10**6]

nan_range = []
start = 0
for i in range(len(data)-1):
    if data[i] + 2 < data[i+1]:
        end = data[i]
        nan_range.append((start, end))
        start = data[i+1]

end_time = time.time()
print('time = %f' % (end_time-start_time))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 100), (200, 300), (400, 500), (600, 700), (800, 900), (1000, 1100), (1200, 1300), (1400, 1500), (2780, 2879)]

time = 0.000942
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It's fast but unfortunately it does not capture the last gap!

Comment: @Celdor yep yesterday i don't have time to finish this. To correct solution simply add gradient to the list :). Code updated

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version.  In short, we find the index values with NaNs (one line), then we find start- and end-points of the consecutive NaNs.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

# Create an object with sample data
w = pd.Series(np.sin(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0,1,2880)))
# Insert a few gaps with missing values
for i in np.arange(0, 1500, 200):
    w.loc[w.index[0]+i:w.index[0]+i+100] = np.nan
w.loc[2880-100:] = np.nan
```

Most of the code is print statements:

```
start_time = time.time()

# find index such that w is NaN
idx = w[ w.isna() ].index

# find the break-points
# idx[1:] is the index (except the first value)
# idx[:-1] is the index (except the last value)
# this allows us to calculate distance from current to previous

print(f'[({idx[0]}, ', end='')

for curr, prev in zip(idx[1:], idx[:-1]):
    diff = curr - prev
    if diff > 1:
        print(f'{prev}),')
        print(f'({curr}, ', end='')
print(f'{idx[-1]})]')

end_time = time.time()
print('time = %f' % (end_time-start_time))

[(0, 100),
(200, 300),
(400, 500),
(600, 700),
(800, 900),
(1000, 1100),
(1200, 1300),
(1400, 1500),
(2780, 2879)]
time = 0.002937
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a more optimised version of your loop:

```
w2 = w.index[w.isna()].tolist()
s = e = w2[0]
l_nans = []
for i in range(1, len(w2)):
    if w2[i] != 1 + e:
        l_nans.append((s, e))
        s = w2[i]
    e = w2[i]
if e - s >= 1:
    l_nans.append((s, e))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 100),
 (200, 300),
 (400, 500),
 (600, 700),
 (800, 900),
 (1000, 1100),
 (1200, 1300),
 (1400, 1500),
 (2780, 2879)]
```

Perf (with `%%timeit`):

```
392 µs ± 9.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You have a start and end pointer, `s` and `e`. Simply assign `ind[i]` to `e` (e will always be equal to the last element you're checking), `if ind[i] - e > 1` means that you moved to another range, so add the range and set `s` to `ind[i]`, then repeat until the end.

At the end, since the loop may break before reaching e - s > 1, check if the last index - the start is bigger than 1, then that mean that the last indexes form a range, so add it to the list.